# Crash when using both Library Desugaring and R8/Proguard/minifyEnabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I have a **multi-module** app (`minSdk 21` , AGP `7.0.0-alpha12`) that crashes on startup in release variant (Proguard/R8 enabled) when using Java 8 desugaring [following this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

I know this error is related to desugaring because if I enable desugaring the error occurs

```
compileOptions {
      coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}
```

Whereas If I disable desugaring the error doesn't occur

```
compileOptions {
      coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled false
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class j$.util.Collection implements non-interface class d.e (declaration of 'j$.util.Collection' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at ja.s.f(Unknown Source:0)
        at h4.g0.<clinit>(:4)
        at y5.d1.C(:1)
        at v8.f.<init>(:2)
        at com.luminarlab.fontboard.KeyboardApp.<init>(:2)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1155)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)
```

I tried fixing the error using `-keep class java.util.** { *; }` in `proguard-rules.pro` but it doesn't change anything.

Any help, hints or answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out the guide on [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) is outdated. As of now it uses `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'` but the latest version is `coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'`.
Updating to the latest version resolved my issue. You can find the latest version [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=desugar#com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs)

Comment: I have a bit similar issue but updating the version did not help. Do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67656105/12204620