# Desugaring - Java 8 Stream API with Proguard crash in release version

Tags: android, java-8, java-stream, proguard, jdk-desugaring

The app **crashes only in its release version** with desugaring Java 8 for Android.

```
compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

This is what we tried but did not work.

```
-keep class java.util.stream.** { *; }
```

The sample code is just using filter

```
List<MovieModel> = someList.stream().filter(it -> !it.getImdbId().equalsIgnoreCase(model.getImdbId())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: j$.util.stream.p cannot be cast to j$.wrappers.p
```

Comment: what is the type of `someList`? and how is `model` declared?

Comment: @Naman same type `List<MovieModel>` coming from the Intent. I tried to keep the model in proguard as well and it did not work, clearly it is not the POJO that has the problem.

Comment: Should be fixed in this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189264383 not officially released yet though

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS, I have the same problem. Did you find the solution? I'm using AGP 7.0.4 and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'`

`tools:desugar_jdk_libs` should upgrade to 1.1.5 or heigher.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html